# MMSE of conditional normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have 2-step experiment:
Flip a fair coin, $C = 0$ or $1$ wp $1/2$.
Than generate normally distribution, $X|C$~$N(C, v)$, while $v$ is known.
I trying to find MMSE estimator.
First I calculate the conditional distribution P(C|X) with bayes rule and than I just take a E:
\begin{align}P(C|X) = \frac{N(C,v)}{N(0, v) + N(1, v)}
\end{align}
Since $C$ can get only $0$,$1$, the $E$ is:
\begin{align}
C_{MMSE} = E[C|X]
= \frac{N(1,v)}{N(0, v) + N(1, v)}
\end{align}

Now I want to prove that this estimator is unbiased. It is easy to show that $E[C] = 1/2$, but I failed to calculate the $E$ of MMSE estimator of $C$.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well, finally i handle it:
\begin{align}
E[C_{MMSE}] = E[E[C|X]] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}C_{MMSE}\cdot f(x)dx
=...=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}